# Certificate Rebind in IIS 10 using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, ssl, iis

I'm trying to enable the "certificate rebind option in IIS 10" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-85/certificate-rebind-in-iis85 using PowerShell.

I found nothing but this, https://delpierosysadmin.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/iis-8-5-enable-automatic-rebind-of-renewed-certificate-via-command-line/

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Why? Cannot you call schtasks from within a PowerShell script?

Comment: @LexLi i could, but i'm not confident enough on the solution provided. As it only creates task scheduler job. There could be any config changes related to it, which wasn't mentioned. If there were no changes included for config, how does IIS reflects this change in IIS manager?

Comment: Well, just checked that task job by enabling on my local system. Seems like it calls appcmd.exe. It must take care of the config changes right?

Comment: When you enable Automatic Certificate Rebind from IIS Manager for a given website, IIS registers a task in the system's Task Scheduler that will trigger upon a certificate-renewal event (event ID 1001) and that will automatically run an appcmd command to unbind the old certificate from the website and bind the new certificate to the website. The task is stored in the CertificateServicesClient folder of the Task Scheduler Library.there are no other configuration changes happen in this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just creating the scheduled task as described in the referenced blog post should be sufficient.

There are no configuration changes in IIS when the you enable the feature in the IIS GUI.

IIS Manager just checks for the existence of a task

```
\Microsoft\Windows\CertificateServicesClient\IIS-AutoCertRebind
```

if such a task exists, regardless of what it does, IIS Manager changes the wording on the link.

Answer (score 6):

In my case the solution to this problem was simple but dumb. I started the IIS-Console using the Server-Manager -> Tools, and got the same error every time I tried to enable the automatic rebind.

After a while of testing I opened a cmd with admin-privileges, ran an mmc and added the IIS-Console there ... and tried the same thing. Well long story short, it worked *facepalm*

Comment: Right-Click to open IIS-Console using Run as Administrator also works.